# vsts -- effort dropdown values on product board

Tags: azure-devops

I use the product board to set the effort for Product Backlog Items.  The project uses a scrum process with effort measured in hours.  However, the default values in the effort dropdown are more in line with Agile level-of-effort estimation.

[here's a picture of the default dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flXBA.png)

When I click the effort number in the backlog, I want the dropdown to have the numbers 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 40 instead.  Is there a way to make that happen?  As a bonus, I'd ideally like only those values to be valid.

Comment: So do you want to estimate work items in hours or in estimation points, if you want to use hours, why you don't want to have 3 hours, or half hour?

Comment: I want to estimate work items in hours.  Because the amount of uncertainty increases with the size of the work item, there's not much sense in trying to decide whether a task is a 7 hour task or an 8 hour task.  In order to make estimation easier, we round up to the numbers I mentioned.

Comment: I think you need to add custom picklist (integer) field and use that as work effort. There are few drawbacks with this solution, like all the default charts won't neccesary work for you.

Comment: That approach is not preferable for a couple of reasons.  First, as you said, reporting becomes more difficult.  I also don't know how to make custom fields show on backlog items in the boards view (as shown in the picture included with the question).